# Substituir variable 'static' List<> por otra solucion para que no se me borre datos al hacer postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

En una página web tengo una variable declarada como static en el inicio:

static public List resultados = new List();

Al principio recojo una lista de datos de productos y lo guardo en esa variable. Luego en diferentes metodos voy accediendo a esta variable para recuperar algun dato del Producto.

El problema es que no me sirve declararla como static porque la pagina es para varios usuarios y los datos se cruzarían. Sino la declaro como static y hago varios postback en la misma página  los datos de esta variable se pierden.

He probado con ViewState de la siguiente manera en el inicio de la clase:

```
public List<Producto> resultados = new List<Producto>();
```

y en el PageLoad()

```
if (!IsPostBack) 
{
    ViewState["resultados"] = resultados;
    ((List<Producto>)ViewState["resultados"]).Clear();
  
    foreach ( DataRow item in dsTablaInicial.Tables["Producto"].Rows )
    {
        ((List<Producto>)ViewState["resultados"]).Add(new Producto()
        {
           Id = Guid.NewGuid();
           Nombre = item["Nombre"];
           categoria = item["Categoria"];
        }
    }

 }
```

Antes de salir del PageLoad() no hay ningún error incluso el ViewState["resultados"] aparece relleno con la dsTablaInicial
En el momento que se sale del PageLoad() aparece este error en VisualStudio

```
El tipo 'Producto' del ensamblado 'App_Code.kozoyqmj, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' no está marcado como serializable.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error se debe a que en tu clase `Producto` debes marcar la clase como serializable de esta manera

```
[Serializable]
public class Producto
{
  //propiedades
}
```

Recuerda que el `ViewState` se envía al cliente y este lo retona al servidor (una especie de ping-pong). Por lo que otra posible solución a tu problema es usar variables de `Session`

```
Session["resultados"] = resultados;
```

Comment: es correcto me faltaba añadir la etiqueta [Serializable]